# Cookie consent for embeded Youtube videos using javascript for GDPR compliance

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, youtube, cookieconsent

Due to GDPR law, it seems we need user consent for even Youtube embeded videos on our website also similar to what we have to do for Google Analytics.

I have been searching through but could find a ways to much help on net or plugin which can get user consent for youTube videos.

We can use `www.youtube-nocookie.com` to embed videos which is not setting http cookies. Instead the alternative domain is setting persistent "super cookies" in the browsers HTML Locale Storage which also requires consent.

I came across one website which required user consent before playing youtube video but i am not sure how they are doing it.

https://edps.europa.eu/press-publications/press-news/videos/cnn-regulators-probe-facebook-over-data-privacy-giovanni_en

another example which shows a way around is below, but this doesn't show a working example 
https://cybot.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/614733-iframe-cookie-consent-with-youtube-example

Comment: Have you tried to do what the page in the last link is showing?

Comment: Second option  uses cookibot 3rd part `javascript:Cookiebot.renew()`. i cant see how this will work as i cant see any script part in the link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjwoyW

Comment: There are many plugins for this but most sites seem to use this one https://cookieconsent.insites.com/demos/

Comment: I have already looked at this one this is a generic one, while as per GDPR we have to see user consent separately also.. which make it difficult honestly and there is lot about Google Analytics and alsmost nothing about YouTube..